# Meaning of cookie icon in Google Chrome address bar

Tags: google-chrome, icons, cookies

What is the meaning of the cookie with an red X mark icon in the Google Chrome address bar?

[image: chrome address bar]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cookie is blocked. This is a new feature in the latest version of Chrome.

You can find more information here:

[Cookies: Manage cookie settings](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95647)

[Video: Google Chrome & Privacy - Browser Cookies](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anfj4V5i7hs&feature=player_embedded)